# CCDT for synchronous message

Tags: ibm-mq, synchronous

Two applications send and receive MQ message. Sending out of a message is done using CCDT (ccdt will decide on the available port for the queue). The receiving end is made sure to listen to the all the available ports through direct connection by specifying the available ports. This setup works for async messages. We have an issue with sync message. All our applications send outgoing messages using CCDT due to which even in case of sync message the response for the message might not be available under the same port as which the message was sent.

Example below
App 1 sends a mq message to App 2. App 2 sends a response back to App 1. Our initial approach was to send message from App 1 to say port "1234" and then App 2 will read from same port and also reply back to same port.

There is now a multi instance queue manager and by introducing CCDT, App 1 can send message to any available port (for ex: "1234", "4321", "3214" are the available ports). App 2 is configured to listen messages from all of the mentioned port. When app 1 now sends a message and using CCDT it is put to port "4321" and waits for a response. App 2 reads the message and sends a reply back but not to the same port 4321. This is because app 2 while sending out message also uses CCDT and it could put the message into any port.

So would like to understand how can we use CCDT in same of sync messages

Comment: I think it would be better if you provide more details what you meant by Async and Sync message. I get a feeling that "sync" means: response message must be consumed by the same application that sent the request? while async means: response can be consumed by any of the sending application.

Comment: Yes that's right. For sync the response to be consumed by the same application. Have updated the summary above

Comment: If you leave replyToQmgr blank it should get filled in by the queue manager that the sending application connects to,  this would allow the server application to reply back to the same qmgr.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: "multi instance" means 1 queue manager than can run on two servers (only active on 1), is this what you really mean? Your description sounds like you just mean 3 different queue managers.

Comment: Yes something like this. We shall explore the application which sends the message back if we could set the replyToQmgr blank

Comment: Its a group queue manager

Comment: Please add your CCDT (redacted) to allow us to understand what might go going on.

Comment: @mukunthraj, you say you want to check the application which sends the message back if you could set the replyToQmgr blank. What you need to do is to let the requester application to leave the ReplyToQMgr blank. The consuming/responding application needs to use the ReplyToQMgr field to address the queue for responding.